# Infopath - Getting User's name from SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath

I am using userName() in an Infopath 2013 form to get a user's name from SharePoint 2013 Online.

It gives me:

```
i:0#.f|membership|fred.bloggs@blah.com
```

Is there an easy way to get this as 'Fred Bloggs'? Or at least strip it so I just get the email address as `fred.bloggs@blah.com`.

Comment: How are your getting username?CSOM?

Comment: Try using a function to substring the username. Something like this: concat(substring-after(usernameField; "i:0#.f|membership|"); substring-before(usernameField; "@"))

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/functions-in-infopath-HP001155281.aspx